# Snowflake - Except operator

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm new to SQL - my company is using Snowflake and I try to write a query using EXCEPT operator. According to the documentation, I should be able to use it - but it doesn't seem to work (UNION for example, works fine). Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please at least include the query, and maybe some sample data as well.

Comment: Can you define "why it does not work" and "what you expect to see"

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT column1 FROM VALUES (1),(2)
EXCEPT
SELECT column1 FROM VALUES (2);
```

yields just the value 1

| COLUMN1 |
| --- |
| 1 |

[MINUS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#minus-except) is the same concept, just different name.

```
SELECT column1 FROM VALUES (2)
MINUS 
SELECT column1 FROM VALUES (1),(2)
```

however returns no rows, because the single row 2 is negated by the 2 in the second set.

Both are a form of a LEFT OUTER JOIN, which is done via a LEFT JOIN and a NULL check in the WHERE.

so the `((2)) minus ((1),(2))` is the same as:

```
WITH data1(col1) as (
    SELECT column1 FROM VALUES (2)
), data2(col1) as (
    SELECT column1 FROM VALUES (1),(2)
)
SELECT d1.col1
FROM data1 AS d1
LEFT JOIN data2 AS d2
    ON d1.col1 = d2.col1
WHERE d2.col1 IS NULL;
```

which returns zero rows, and they are all present in the seconds table.